# Who's interpretation of terms is correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

#### Background

My business teacher on his board wrote the equation $TP\div TM = P_m$ (In this equation, $T=\text{Time in years}$, $P=\text{Principle}$, $M=\text{Time in months}$, and $P_m=\text{Monthly Payment}$.) This equation is being used to calculate the monthly payment for a simple interest equation.

---

My teacher wrote the equation as $(TP)\div(TM)=P_m$ in other places on the board

My teacher says that the $\div$ operator separates the equation into two terms; $TP$ and $TM$. I think that the expression can be represented as a single terms; $\frac{TP}{TM}$ (And I was taught the separator of terms was a $+$ or $-$. Which of these interpretations is correct?

Edit: I know this is a rather trivial topic, but my teacher is very insistent and I am not one to just deny what my teacher says without knowing for sure.

Comment: If you look it up in various dictionaries, it appears that *term* can refer both to quantities separated by $+$ and $-$ as well as to the parts of a ratio or fraction. One can reduce a fraction to its lowest terms for instance. So your teacher is correct, but the term *term* has a second usage in mathematics ;) And many more outside of maths.

Comment: @RossMillikan The question isn't about the order of operations, it's about what the terms of the equation are. And $P_m$ represents monthly payment not Principals times months

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Certainly $(TP)\div(TM)=\frac{TP}{TM}$. Are you asking whether it's correct to call $TP$ and $TM$ "terms" (as opposed to "divisor" and "dividend" or something)?